# How can i invoke a shell command from python which includes regexp?

Tags: python, shell

How can I invoke a shell command from python which includes regexp (i.e., `cat filename*`).

I wrote:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["cat", filename + "*"])
```

but I am getting an error

> cat filename* no such file or directory.

I'd like to force the shell to treat "*" as a regexp and not as a string. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: What file do you want `cat` to open? Could you give an example?

Comment: i have a folder where i have splitted a file with name filaname in : filaneme00,filaename01,...filenamen. and i want afterwards to compose with this: cat filename*>filename_original_version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIRST it's not regular expression it's shell expansion (glob) that you seem to want to execute.  Which means that you should invoke /bin/sh to execute cat.  The following should do the trick:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh", "-c", "cat", filename + "*"]);
```

Now /bin/sh will actually perform the asterisk expansion for you and you'll get the desired result.

Or you can use globbing library to do globbing expansions yourself (i.e. do the work that shell does):

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["cat"] + glob.glob(filename + "*"));
```

glob.glob() returns the array of files that match the globbing.

Comment: When i am using the glob.glob ( filename + "\*" ) the files are not combined  in alphabetical order as when you open the shell and type cat filename\* . When i invoke a new shell i am getting this: cat: -: Input/output error. The same is happening with @Kirk's answers

Comment: Yes, `glob` uses the order the files are stored in the directory, which is not alphabetical. You could put `sorted(...)` around the `glob.glob()` call.

Comment: Ahmed, the `shell=True` argument to `Popen()` accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Ah :-) Thanks for that... my python 2.x is weak. I started using it from 3.x

Answer (score 6):

Use an underlying shell to expand your globs:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["cat",filename+"*"], shell=True)
```

Alternatively, use `glob.glob` to expand your arguments before running the command:

```
import glob
pid = subprocess.Popen(["cat"] + glob.glob(filename + "*"))
```